# Problem/bug with `RandomVariate` and `FirstPassageTimeDistribution`?

Tags: bugs, random, distributions, markov-chains

```
tmat = Uncompress[
   "1:eJxTTMoPSuNjYGAoZgESPpnFJai8TCDNkMYEEuIAEkGJJZn5eYk5mYxATiYTHjkW\
AnJgg0kisDgMr+\
sIuQCfryh1GEGzCQYNNcKOilGJbjJlrqN2VBLpOsIxS5OopEbY0S4qKXQdjaOS/\
JilR1SSFXZ0i0pSXUffqCQhZgcgKon0/QBFJTkOo4gAGQwAi1ootQ=="];

mproc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, tmat];

fpd = FirstPassageTimeDistribution[mproc, Length@tmat];

RandomVariate[fpd]
```

Is met with:

[image]

10.3/Windows 7

Seems fine in 9.x/Windows.

Comment: Version 11 also chokes on this.

Comment: @J.M. - That's a bummer: some important stuff that was broken in 9.x for MC got addressed, but some basic functionality gets busted (it appears it might be related to PDF/CDF handling for the chain under the covers - I also see some strange results using them directly). Tagging as bug and when/if time permits, reporting to WRI. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: This works in 12.2.

Comment: @JimB - well, +1, thanks for the ping!